# Qt Segmentation fault at exec()

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, qapplication

I have a very strange problem while trying to run a `QProcess` in a class `HmiApplication`, which is derived from `QApplication`.

The application throws a *SIGSEGV* in line 6 of `main.cpp`. This occurs only if line 11 of `hmiapplication.cpp` is commented out (If I don't `qDebug()` the stdout of the QProcess).

For the sake of simplicity and clarity, I didn't handle any return values while creating the QProcess.

main.cpp

```
#include "hmiapplication.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HmiApplication hmi(argc, argv);
    return hmi.exec(); // LINE 6 - SIGSEGV
}
```

hmiapplication.h

```
#ifndef HMIAPPLICATION_H
#define HMIAPPLICATION_H

#include <QApplication>
#include <QProcess>

class HmiApplication : public QApplication
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    HmiApplication(int argc, char **argv);
    virtual ~HmiApplication();

private:
    QProcess *macFinder = nullptr;
};

#endif // HMIAPPLICATION_H
```

hmiapplication.cpp

```
#include "hmiapplication.h"

HmiApplication::HmiApplication(int argc, char **argv) : QApplication(argc, argv)
{
    macFinder = new QProcess(this);
    macFinder->start("arping", QStringList() << "-c 2" << "192.168.1.1");
    macFinder->waitForReadyRead();
    QString ret(macFinder->readAllStandardOutput());
    ret = ret.mid(ret.indexOf('[') + 1, 17);
    qDebug() << ret; // LINE 11
}

HmiApplication::~HmiApplication()
{
}
```

**EDIT:**
If I add `QVector<Camera*> cameras;` to the header and

```
for(quint8 i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Camera *cam = new Camera(i);
    cameras.append(cam);
}
```

to the source file, it doesn't matter whether or not I remove the `qDebug()` line and will throw a segmentation fault in both cases.

`Camera` is a derived class of `QLabel` and is perfectly working without the `QProcess` mentionened above.

Comment: What if you replace `qDebug()` with `printf("%s", qPrintable(ret));`?

Comment: @vahancho The application will throw a SIGSEGV at the exact same line as without `qDebug()`.

Comment: Change `int argc` to `int &argc` as the first parameter to the `HmiApplication` constructor.

Comment: Are you sure that `ret` is set to what you expect before the `ret = ret.mid(...);` line?  And does it actually contain a `[` character?  `QString::indexOf()` returns -1 if the character isn't found and `QString::mid()` returns a "null string" if the range is out of bounds, so maybe the segfault is from trying to print this "null" QString.

Comment: @CandyGumdrop I know, this is just quick and dirty, but the current version of `arping` will output `...[mac-adress]...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`QApplication` constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication) accepts its first parameter by reference...

```
QApplication::QApplication(int &argc, char **argv)
```

With the documentation also warning that...

> The data referred to by argc and argv must stay valid for the entire
>   lifetime of the QApplication object. In addition, argc must be greater
>   than zero and argv must contain at least one valid character string.

However, you pass `argc` by *value* to the `HmiApplication`.  Hence the `QApplication` constructor receives a non-const reference to the local copy which will go out of scope at the end of the `HmiApplication` ctor leading to undefined behaviour later on.

Change the signature of your constructor to...

```
HmiApplication::HmiApplication(int &argc, char **argv)
```

Comment: Thank you. I should've checked the constructor documentation of QApplication myself...